# 403 Forbidden, When I try to call PowerBI API to push dataset or get all workspaces

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I am currently working on PowerBI integration. I have set-up an application and granted access to the PowerBI Service APIs.

But after getting the access token, I get a 403 when I try to call https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets

I get 403 even if I try to call the API to get all Workspaces even though I have that permission as well.

Here is my sample code:

```
        String datasetJson = "{\"name\": \"Sales101\", \"tables\": " + "[{\"name\": \"Product\", \"columns\": "
                + "[{ \"name\": \"ProductID\", \"dataType\": \"Int64\"}, "
                + "{ \"name\": \"Name\", \"dataType\": \"string\"}, "
                + "{ \"name\": \"Category\", \"dataType\": \"string\"},"
                + "{ \"name\": \"IsCompete\", \"dataType\": \"bool\"},"
                + "{ \"name\": \"ManufacturedOn\", \"dataType\": \"DateTime\"}" + "]}]}";
```

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().followRedirects(false).build();
    RequestBody formBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), datasetJson);

    Request request = new Request.Builder().addHeader("Authorization", String.format("Bearer {0}", accessToken))
            .url("https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets").post(formBody).build();

    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    okhttp3.Response response = call.execute();
```

Please note that my access token seem to have the right permissions. Please see below excerpt when I decoded my JWT:

```
    "scp": "App.Read.All Capacity.Read.All Capacity.ReadWrite.All Content.Create Dashboard.Read.All 
    Dashboard.ReadWrite.All Dataflow.Read.All Dataflow.ReadWrite.All Dataset.Read.All 
    Dataset.ReadWrite.All Gateway.Read.All Gateway.ReadWrite.All Report.Read.All Report.ReadWrite.All 
    StorageAccount.Read.All StorageAccount.ReadWrite.All Tenant.Read.All Tenant.ReadWrite.All 
    Workspace.Read.All Workspace.ReadWrite.All",
```

Also, please note that I am a normal PowerBI user. To use the APIs.. . I did the following:

- Created a new app with client Id and Secret
- Set-up the right permissions for APIs

I didn't do any changes on PowerBI... I assume the API permissions are enough?

Guidance is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

this is resolved. The issue was with the String.format function I was using.